# Loading an image on a PictureBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a game with multiple characters. I already know the code on how to load an image from a picturebox. Which is this

PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\jp.jpg")

But My problem is. I want my program to automatically search the image from the folder where the picture is in. without specifying the exact location of the image so that if anyone tried to copy my program the image still load.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your images in a path relative to the application (or a path relative to a well know directory like ProgramData or MyDocuments) then build your path to pass to Image.FromFile.

As an example

```
Dim imageFileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Images", "jp.jpg")
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imageFileName)
```

This will load the image specified from a folder named Images that should be located as a subfolder of the folder where your application has been started.
In this way, it is more easy to copy all the application folder and its subfolders and move them to another PC. Of course this is only the tip of the iceberg, many details are unknown from your question like if you use a database or if you need some other assemblies to be installed on the target machine.